How can TransformerXL be used for text classification?
For a normal encoder-only Transformer like BERT, I know we can add a CLS token to the input that "aggregates" information from all other tokens. We can then attach a MLP to this token at the final layer to produce the class predictions.
My question is, how would this work for TransformerXL, which processes a (long) input in small chunks? It must output a CLS token every chunk, right? Do we then only use the last of these CLS tokens (which is produced when TrXL consumes the final chunk of the input) to make the class prediction, and compute the loss from this? Or is there a totally different way to do this?
